# Sitecore: Item display name does not support parenthesis

Tags: sitecore

I changed the display name of an item from Item1 to (This is the new title)

However, in the tree, while the closing ) shows up, the opening appears encoded.
It shows as:

```
&#40;This is the new title)
```

How do I fix this please?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug, introduced in 9.3 iirc. Reference number 393368. As far as I'm aware, there isn't a patch yet for it, but you can patch it yourself by replacing the faulty pipeline.

Look at `Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.Save` class in `Sitecore.Kernel`. In the deep nested `Process()` method, you'll see this code (reflected with dotPeek):

```
if (this.NeedsHtmlTagEncode(field1))
  field1.Value = WebUtil.SafeEncode(field1.Value);
```

The `NeedsHtmlTagEncode` returns true for `DisplayName` (for some unknown reason). You can workaround this issue by replacing the Save processor with one that inherits the old one and overrides the `protected virtual bool NeedsHtmlTagEncode(SaveArgs.SaveField field)` method and just let it return false. Then you just patch out the existing processor with your own one with the xpath `/sitecore/processors/saveUI/processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.Save, Sitecore.Kernel']`.

Answer (score 2):

An update since we just encountered this in one of our projects:

In addition to the bug mikaelnet wrote about, which affects when you change the Display name field in the Content Editor `Appearance` section and then save the item, there is a second bug that affects the Display name ribbon menu button you are using here.

From what I found, the problem is in the `/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/Prompt/prompt.js` file and was introduced some time between 9.0 and 9.3.

This is the 9.0 version:

```js
  function ok_click(evt) {
    evt && Event.stop(evt);
​
    var maxlength = (dialogArguments.maxLength != null ? parseInt(dialogArguments.maxLength, 10) : 0);
​
    if (dialogArguments.validation != null) {
      var re = new RegExp(dialogArguments.validation);
    }
​
    var result = $("Value").value;
    ...
```

The 9.3 version has an added `sanitizeHtml` call:

```js
  function ok_click(evt) {
    evt && Event.stop(evt);
​
    var maxlength = (dialogArguments.maxLength != null ? parseInt(dialogArguments.maxLength, 10) : 0);
​
    if (dialogArguments.validation != null) {
      var re = new RegExp(dialogArguments.validation);
    }
​
    var result = sanitizeHtml($("Value").value);
    ...
```

I believe both issues were reported in the mentioned bug and we have seen a patched version of the `sanitizeHtml()` method that fixes some encoding issues, but I don't see why they would encode the result in the first place so the underlying issue you are seeing is still there.